# Добавление нескольких ссылок на картинки в одно поле таблицы mysql.

Tags: php, html, mysql, fileupload

Интересует такой момент. Пишу сайт-каталог и для него админ панель, через которую загружаю данные. Но тут столкнулся с проблемой, что не могу к одному товару прикрепить несколько изображений. Как можно реализовать данную идею средствами php и mysql? Какую таблицу в базе создать для добавления туда ссылок на изображения с диска? И как программно загружать ссылки на изображения в нее? 
(в php и mysql почти ноль знаний, все делаю на примерах, а при их реализации разбираюсь как работает тот или иной тег)
Если можете, распишите пожалуйста детально решение вопроса, буду очень благодарен!

Answer (score 0):

Можно создать таблицу `images` для изображений с полем `productId` -- идентификатором товара, которому изображения принадлежат. Таким образом одно изображение будет связано с одним товаром, но один товар может быть связан со многими изображениями. Такая связь обычно и называется "один ко многим".

```
create table `images` (
    `id` int unsigned not null auto_increment,
    `productId` int unsigned not null,
    `url` varchar(255) not null,
    primary key (`id`),
    key `productId` (`productId`) -- этот индекснужен для быстрого поиска всех изображений товара
)
engine InnoDB
comment 'Изображения тоаров';
```

Для получения всех изображений надо сделать дополнительный запрос к таблице `images` ограничив выборку условием `productId = <ID товара>`. Ссылки в такую таблицу загружаются как обычно, только дополнительно проставляется идентификатор товара.

Обратите внимание, что при удалении записи товара из соответствующей таблицы, потребуется удалять и связанные с ней записи в таблице картинок. Это можно делать отдельным запросом или добавить [внешние ключи](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) и база сама удалит связанные данные.

В качестве альтернативы отдельной таблице можно использовать поле с типом `json`, в которое помещать список ссылок.